# Android, camera in my app is rotated

Tags: android

i'm opening the Camera in my app and the cam display is rotated by 90deg allways even when i rotating the device in my hands.

the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;    
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class CameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
        private SurfaceHolder holder;
        private Camera camera;
        private Context context;
        public CameraSurfaceView(Context context) 
        {
                super(context);

                //Initiate the Surface Holder properly
                this.holder = this.getHolder();
                this.holder.addCallback(this);
                this.holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
                this.context = context;
          }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                int height) {               

        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and  begin
            // the preview.
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            Camera.Size size = previewSizes.get(0);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);           

            Display display = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

            if(display.getOrientation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
            {
                //parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);                           
                parameters.setRotation(90);
            }

            if(display.getOrientation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
            {
                //parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);                           
            }

            if(display.getOrientation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
            {
                //parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);               
            }

            if(display.getOrientation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
            {
                //parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
                parameters.setRotation(180);
            }                
            camera.setParameters(parameters);                
            camera.startPreview();              
        }    
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
             try
             {
                     //Open the Camera in preview mode
                     this.camera = Camera.open();
                     this.camera.setPreviewDisplay(this.holder);
             }
             catch(IOException ioe)
             {
                     ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
             }              
        }    
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // Surface will be destroyed when replaced with a new screen
            //Always make sure to release the Camera instance
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;              
        }
  }
```

Any ideas ? Thanks

p.s how do i know what is the correct choose for my device in the line

```
List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
```

Comment: It's a bug based on the hardware settings on some phones. Android can't be patched to fix it since it's hardware. You will just have to rotate the image in code.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code, when i wanted to display the camera preview correctly

```
 Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.set("jpeg-quality", 100);
            parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
            parameters.set("rotation", 90);
            parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);

            parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example code given in [`Camera.setDisplayOrientation(int degrees)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29) method reference. Note that you should perform these actions before calling `setPreviewDisplay (SurfaceHolder)`

Comment: Try using `Camera.setDisplayOrientation(degrees)` instead of `Camera.Parameters.setRotation(degrees)`